# Force Load (Reload) a VAR that may be an IFrame using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to force reload an iframe (as a var) when I rewrite an .ASPX video stream page's embed params. Essentially I have 3 iframes on .ASPX page that utilize same .ASPX page source. These Iframes may or may not be in focus but are triggered using a .LIVE click (on a thumbnail set) and the .next function in Jquery handles the swaps dependent on next DOM element next to thumbnail.
Below: the VAR 'img' may be an IMG or an IFRAME so I need to test first if the VAR is an iframe, if yes then force reload the source. The issue is that we are essentially changing params on the Iframe SRC page (.aspx) which in turn remotely loads a video and then ultimatley is reflected in the main Iframe. My jquery/js is not as strong as it should be so please be kind in your reponses. Thanks in advance. :)

JQuery Snippet:

```
$('.workThumbnails img').live('click', function () {
                $('img', $(this).parents('.workThumbnails')).toggleClass('whiteBorder', false);
                $(this).toggleClass('whiteBorder', true);
                var img = $(this).next('iframe,img');
                var work = $(this).parents('.ourWork');
                $('.workContent *', work).fadeTo('slow', 0.0, function () {
                    $('.workContent', work).empty();
                    $('.workContent', work).append(img.clone());
                    $('.workContent *', work).fadeTo('slow', 1.0);
                });
            });
```

HTML Snippet: `<iframe width="675" height="379" src="../../video.aspx?vid=448679&cid=1c0b792573224ebcb925e5306b333907" frameborder="0"></iframe>`

Answer (score 0):

```
var img = $(this).next('iframe,img'); // I would consider renaming this variable
if(img.is('iframe')){
    img.load(function(){ /* callback */ });
    img.contents().get(0).location.reload();
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

```
if(img.is('img'))img.attr('src', img.attr('src'));
else img[0].contentDocument.location.reload();
```